# On powers of binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients

Consider $(1+n)^k$. Where both n, k are natural numbers.

We have binomial expansion $\sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{k}{i}n^i $

Then we have for each i-th term, certain powers of n(at least $>=i$).

As i increases, will powers of n increase too(not necessarily strictly)?

This seems trivial, but I don't see how to ensure it.

p. s. Or under what specific conditions on k will this hypothesis be true?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true:

$$\binom{6}{3}2^3 = 5*2^5\qquad \binom{6}{4}2^4 = 15*2^4$$

---

A sufficient condition for it to happen is that  $k<n^2$.

Notice that if $k+1$ and $n$ are coprime and $k\ge n^2$, then there exists a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks. But could there be any sufficient conditions(by setting some special k) such that this becomes true?

Comment: if $k\ge n^2$ and $k+1$ is coprime with $n$, then there's a counterexample

Comment: @user154020 edited